# Why is >>= faster than concatMap when they ought to be the same thing?

Tags: performance, list, haskell, ghc

Last night, I was writing some recreational code, and at some point I replaced a `concatMap` with `>>=` and saw a ~10% speedup in my code.

I was under the impression the definition of `>>=` for `[]` was exactly `concatMap`, so I am a little confused.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In base 4.8 `(>>=)` is implemented (see [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-726)) as:

```
xs >>= f = [y | x <- xs, y <- f x]
```

and `concatMap` is using a more complicated builder(source [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#concatMap))

```
concatMap :: Foldable t => (a -> [b]) -> t a -> [b]
concatMap f xs = build (\c n -> foldr (\x b -> foldr c b (f x)) n xs)
```

Comment: Interesting. I can't help but think that a `Foldable` that is also an `Alternative` is equivalent to a `Monad`....

Comment: @AJFarmar why would you think that? I don't know how that makes any sense

Comment: @user3217013 `bind' fa f = foldr (<|>) empty $ foldr (:) [] (fmap f fa)` where `bind' :: (Foldable f, Applicative f) => f a -> (a -> f b) -> f b`. QED.

Comment: @AJFarmar Probably that `foldr (:) []` throws away all the structure of the thing being folded, so that `bind' m return === m` fails for many otherwise law-abiding `Foldable`+`Alternative`s. Even if you skip that and define `bind' fa f = foldr (<|>) empty (fmap f fa)` I'd have the same concern -- that `foldr (<|>) empty v` may not have the same "shape" as `v`.

Comment: @erdeszt Why isn't `concatMap` specialized to the more efficient version when `t` is known to be `[]`? (Perhaps just oversight by the library authors?)

Comment: @DanielWagner I don't actually know, might worth asking on irc(or opening a pr).